# Getting ERROR while starting JBoss server

Tags: spring, hibernate, web-services, jboss

i am new in using `JBoss` server. I had configuring JNDI lookup in `JBoss` server and integrated with eclipse. but getting below error while running server. not getting what is the root cause. please help me

```
18:01:22,925 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/PMSystemService]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158) [spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    ... 20 more

18:01:23,018 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-7) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.3 (SNAPSHOT 20110825) for context '/PMSystemService'
18:01:25,343 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
18:01:25,936 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Error listenerStart
18:01:25,936 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context [/PMSystemService] startup failed due to previous errors
18:01:25,936 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/PMSystemService]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
18:01:25,936 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/PMSystemService]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:172) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:541) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142) [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3465) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3970) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3888) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_17]
```

this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pmsystemservice</groupId>
  <artifactId>PMSystemService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>PMSystemService</name>
  <description>PMSystemService</description>

  <organization>
        <name>Cluster</name>
        <url>http://clustersolution.com</url>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cocoon</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocoon-configuration-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cocoon</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocoon-spring-configurator</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DS dependencies : END -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring security module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring security module -->

        <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
            Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
            Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
            this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
            spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
            spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
            Container and is generally always defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
            Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
            and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
            JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and 
            TestNG This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for 
            the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END: Spring dependencies -->

        <!-- BEGIN: Rest Easy dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.b2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.12</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- END: Rest Easy dependencies -->
        <!-- concrete Log4J Implementation for SLF4J API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START: java mail dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END: java mail dependencies -->
        <!-- Because the JDK1.6 already include the Java Activation API, otherwise 
            this could generate ClassLoading and Linkage errors -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle Driver -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>com.oracle</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>11.2.0.2.0</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <!-- MYSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0.7.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- BEGIN: Dozer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END: Dozer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

this is applicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="sbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/PMSystemService" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="sbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/PMSystem" />
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    </bean> -->



    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="false">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="sbDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.Country</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.User</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.Brand</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.Promotion</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.ApiAccess</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.ProductType</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.Menu</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.OperationLog</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.UserRole</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.CustRedemption</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.PackCodeSet</value>
                <value>com.pmsystemservice.common.domain.PromotionBatch</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">100</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>PMSystemService</display-name>
    <!-- <context-param> <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value> 
        </context-param> <listener> <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class> 
        </listener> -->

    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Default Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Default Spring MVC Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>upcAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>upcAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Add your web.xml config, looks like applicationcontext.xml has wrong path

Comment: I had added applcationContext.xml file in the web.xml again getting same error..

Comment: where is your applicationContext.xml places? is it in resources or web-inf folder?

Answer (score 0):

The file `applicationContext.xml` should be defined in the web descriptor file `web.xml`, otherwise JBoss/application won't be able to find it. Assuming that you placed `applicationContext.xml` in `\src\main\resources`, add this snippet to your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```